# .htaccess not working in one case

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite in .htaccess provided by aruba.it hosting,
but I've a strange behaviour.
My goal is to remove .php extension, so for example:

> www.mydomain.com/section/page

should load

> www.mydomain.com/section/page.php

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)?$ $1/$2.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

Now I'll describe the strange behaviour.
If I put in my browser a URL referring to a page which **does not** exist (a part from extension), .php is added.

So:

> www.mydomain.com/section/sdflkjcb

where **sdflkjcb.php** does **not** exist, gives me (correctly) this output

> The requested URL /section/sdflkjcb.php was not found on this server.

Please note that **.php** is added to the searched page.

===============================

Instead:

> www.mydomain.com/section/page

where **page.php** does **exist**, gives me (oddly) this output

> The requested URL /section/page was not found on this server.

Please note that **.php** is **not** added this time.

===============================

Obviously:

> www.mydomain.com/section/page.php

display the correct page.

===============================

Some notes:

Adding or removing RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f/-d does not change anything.

I had to add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)php$, otherwise the rule would be applied recursively

I added ?one=$1&two=$2&three=%{REQUEST_URI} just to check values. Adding or removing it does not change anything.

Thank you.

---

*Edit on 21.06.17 as suggested by @anubhava*

This is another example.

.htaccess only rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(dev/|a*)(lineup)/matchReport2/([A-Z]+)/(.+)?$ $1$2/matchReport2015.php?ID_Match=$4&MatchType=$3 [NC]
```

URL tested:

> www.mydomain.eu/dev/lineup/matchReport2/CHM/997

works!

===============================

.htaccess only rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(dev/|a*)(lineup)/matchReport2015/([A-Z]+)/(.+)?$ $1$2/matchReport2015.php?ID_Match=$4&MatchType=$3 [NC]
```

URL tested:

> www.mydomain.eu/dev/lineup/matchReport2015/CHM/997

does not work...

Please note that the only difference between the working example and the other is **matchReport2** vs **matchReport2015**. And that *www.mydomain.eu/dev/lineup/matchReport2015.php* is an existing file on filesystem, while *www.mydomain.eu/dev/lineup/matchReport2* is not. So far, every test I made is consistent with this rule: if the URL exists as a file (ignoring the extension), then rules are ignored.

Is this a configuration I can change in .htaccess file? I cannot manage Apache config. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
   CheckSpelling off
   CheckCaseOnly off
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/$2.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Is not working. Also this rule gives me: The requested URL /section/page was not found on this server.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have always the same output. Please read carefully what I described. The extension is not added just in some cases.

Comment: Indeed. In fact, I wrote something strange is happening. For example:
URL: http://www.domain.eu/dev/lineup/matchReport2/CHM/997
with Rule: RewriteRule ^(dev/|a*)(lineup)/matchReport2/([A-Z]+)/(.+)?$   $1$2/matchReport2015.php?ID_Match=$4&MatchType=$3 [NC]
works!
Instead:
URL: http://www.domain.eu/dev/lineup/matchReport2015/CHM/997
with Rule:
RewriteRule ^(dev/|a*)(lineup)/matchReport2015/([A-Z]+)/(.+)?$   $1$2/matchReport2015.php?ID_Match=$4&MatchType=$3 [NC]
does NOT!

Comment: Even http://htaccess.mwl.be/ tells me that my rule should works, but it doesn't. The rule is not working only when the rule contains the exact page filename. Is this a setting or something?

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Post your complete .htaccess by editing question and write clearly each test case that is not passing and what are your expected outcomes.

Comment: Ok, sorry. What I wrote in the main question is already a good test case. It seems to me that, if the URL correspond to a file (a part from extension), then no rule is applied. If a change just a single character in the URL, then the rules are applied. It must be an Apache configuration or something like that...

Comment: Ok! The solution you provided gives me "Internal server error", but, if I remove both +Indexes and +FollowSymLinks it works! Thanks! Also the <IfModule> tag is not necessary. The only important thing is: Options -MultiViews